# Designing a logger to dump user-defined structures

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, derived-class

I have some user defined structs (which can't be changed) that i want to store in a map
in my Logger class.
i.e.

```
class Logger {
private:
map<string, vector<myType*> > myLog;
}
```

Of course, I can't do this, since Logger isn't a template class. I don't see enough reason to change that.

So, I created a BaseClass to get around the fact that the user-defined structs don't inherit from a common base.

```
class MyTypeBase {
}

template <typename T>
class MyTypeDerived : MyTypeBase {
void DoStuff(const T* tPtr);

private:
vector<T> myList;
}
```

to make my Logger class look like:

```
class Logger {
LogState(const A* aPtr); 
LogState(const B* bPtr); 

private:
map<string, vector<MyTypeBase*> > myLog;
}
```

I'm using overloaded versions of LogState to get around the fact that a templated Logger doesn't make sense to me yet.

The problem I'm facing is that within LogState(..), I want to call DoStuff to work on the input. Since my base class doesn't have this function and isn't templated, I can't call it.

In the client code, I'd like it be:

```
Logger::LogState(aPtr);
Logger::LogState(bPtr);
```

The Logger should do some voodoo magic to push these states into the map and work on them in a seamless fashion.

I saw a few questions similar to this, wherein a few comments mentioned boost::any and boost::shared_ptr; if someone can elaborate on these options, it'd be very helpful.

Thank you!

EDIT 1:
Its kinda stupid that I wanted my Logger class to have a LogState method per structure I intend to dump. This, coupled with wanting to use a single container (the map) for all these types exacerbated my problem.

Let's say I have a StateLogger template class (a singleton) that solves my problem above.
All the good stuff is generated at compile time for me and I get to store packets for every structure I want to.

My Logger class (also a singleton), will be something that the StateLoggers interact with.
This way, I'd have decoupled the state specific logic from the generic logic.

Let me mull over this for some more time. Rubber duck problem solving is so cool.